# JOptionPane cursor

Tags: java, swing, cursor, joptionpane

I have some problem with the cursor when using JOprionPane. I set a cursor to the pharent frame, then show a dialog using this:

```
Object[] possibilities = {"ham", "spam", "yam"};
String s = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(MagicCollectorClient.getMainFrame(),"Complete the sentence:\n\"Green eggs and...\"",
            "Customized Dialog",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,null,possibilities,"ham");
```

It show the dialog, but change the cursor to the default system cursor until I close  the dialog. is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? Yes it's possible, you have to "unbundle" the JOptionPane from the static method helper as you wish to do something special with it. This unfortunately means you have a little more work to do, but nothing too scary.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame parent = new JFrame();
    parent.setSize(400, 400);
    parent.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    parent.setVisible(true);

    Object[] possibilities = { "ham", "spam", "yam" };

    // raw pane
    JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(
            "Complete the sentence:\n\"Green eggs and...\"",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null,
            possibilities, possibilities[0]);

    // create a dialog for it with the title
    JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("Customized Dialog");

    // special code - in this case make the cursors match
    dialog.setCursor(parent.getCursor());

    // show it
    dialog.setVisible(true);

    // blocking call, gets the selection
    String s = (String) optionPane.getValue();

    System.out.println("Selected " + s);
}
```